# Magento Sales/Order/Grid change color depending on status

Tags: php, magento

I am overriding on my module the sales grid to get different reports and i was trying to set a different color if order status is "complete" etc.
Here is my approach , it is not giving errors but doesn't seem to work.

```
    class Mycustom_Salesorderitemgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Items_Grid_Renderer_Order
        extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
    {
        public function render(Varien_Object $row)
        {
            $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
            $html ='<a href="' . $this->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getData('order_id'), 'key' => $this->getCacheKey())) . '" target="_blank" title="' . $value . '" >' . $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()) . '</a>';
            return $html;

// here i am trying to add the color to mass status, after finding solution i will add seperate colors based on status
            $truncateLength = 255;
            // stringLength() is for legacy purposes
            if ($this->getColumn()->getStringLimit()) {
                $truncateLength = $this->getColumn()->getStringLimit();
            }
            if ($this->getColumn()->getTruncate()) {
                $truncateLength = $this->getColumn()->getTruncate();
            }
            $text = Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate(parent::_getValue($row), $truncateLength);
            if ($this->getColumn()->getEscape()) {
                $text = $this->escapeHtml($text);
            }
            if ($this->getColumn()->getNl2br()) {
                $text = nl2br($text);
            }
             if ($this->getColumn()->getStatusLabel() == array('processing', 'waiting', 'pending', 'almost', 'telephone')) {

            $yesterday = strtotime("-24 hours", Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp());
            $yesterday = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date(null, $yesterday);

            if ($row->getCreatedAt() > $yesterday) {
                $text = '<span style="color: red !important; font-weight: bold;">' . $text . '</span>';
            };
        }
            return $text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting value in return $text?

Comment: i do not think so at the current code. How can i check?If i change a little bit this code i can make it work and change for example the color of the Rows ID for the past 24 hours but i am trying to make it work on the order status. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the method below to your Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid class (or to the class which overrides it):

```
public function getRowClass($order)
{
    if ($order->getStatus() == 'canceled') {
        return 'red-row';
    }
}
```

This code will add class="red-row" for every row where the order status is "canceled".
Hope that this will help